# Is it possible to Delete Fields on Records using Data Loader?

Tags: sales-cloud

Is there any way we can delete fields on records using data loader

Comment: Do you mean remove the value of a field or remove fields from the object definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot delete a field using Data Loader.

Data Loader is a client application for the bulk import or export of data. Use it to **insert, update, delete, or export Salesforce records**.

For more detail, refer this guide [Data Loader guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/data_loader.htm)

**To Delete the fields**, follow this steps :-

1. From the management settings for the field’s object, go to Fields.
2. Click Del next to the name of the field.
3. When prompted, select the Yes, I want to delete the custom field checkbox to confirm, and click Delete.

Deleted custom fields and their data are stored until your org permanently deletes them or 15 days has elapsed, whichever happens first. Until that time, you can restore the field and its data. For information on restoring deleted custom fields and relationships, see [Manage Deleted Custom Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_managing_deleted_fields.htm&type=5)

**Note** :-

Following are some notes to be considered before deleting a field:

1. Before deleting a custom field, consider where it’s referenced. You can’t delete a custom field that’s referenced elsewhere. For example, you can’t delete a custom field that’s referenced by a field update or Apex.
2. You can’t delete a field if that field is being updated by a background job, such as an update to a roll-up summary field. Wait until the background job finishes, and try again.
3. When you delete a custom field, all of the field history data is deleted and changes are no longer tracked.
4. A background process periodically runs that cleans up metadata associated with deleted custom fields. This process will affect the Last Modified Date and Last Modified By fields on page layouts, record types, and custom objects.

Reference :- [Delete Field](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.deleting_fields.htm&type=5)